# GDB cannot access memory on iPhone 6.01

Tags: ios, gdb

Doing some application testing, and trying to reverse an app.  I am running the gdb from the newest SDK on an iPhone running ios 6.01.

No matter what I try, I always get the same error "Cannot access memory at address 0x2000"

I have tried different versions of gdb, all seem to do the same thing.  Has anyone been able to get by this on iOS 6.01?

Comment: What do you mean by "reverse an app"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to remove Address Space Layout Randomization.

A few possibilities for doing so:

1. [SecurityLearn](http://www.securitylearn.net/2013/05/23/disable-aslr-on-ios-applications/)
2. [Magic iOS forum](http://magicios.org/topic/3002-how-to-remove-aslr/)

Comment: How can I implement ASLR in iOS app, if you know by chance